# Testing child component input in Angular

Tags: angular, testing

I am testing an Angular component that looks like this:

```
<div><my-sub-component [items]="items"></my-sub-component></div>
```

How can I write a test that would fail as soon as I remove the *[items]="items"* part from my component's template?

Comment: protractor test, that will check that list is not empty on UI.

Comment: You could create a Jasmine spec to check that the child component input is being set, check out ngMocks (https://github.com/ike18t/ng-mocks) and here's a post on how to write the test https://www.denieffe.com/2019/06/angular-testing-child-component-inputs.html